# How can I start ajax push website (activemq or cometd or something else)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, activemq-classic, cometd, bayeux

I want to start an application which will use ajax push, however the web server should be configured properly and i don't know how to start on server side components.

I wanted to start with [dojo's cometd](http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/) and then read some blogs saying that [activeMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) is older and flag carrier on ajax push thing, but there was also another blog saying that it is very hard to set-up and get it work.

Now i'm confused before giving a start, please tell me my way :) What's the optimum way of configuring an ajax push environment?

Sinan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At PHP conference in Slovenia, it was said that Meteor is the best server for Comet.

Comment: Found my notes, there is also Meteor JS library that handles cross-browser issues for you :)

Answer (score 2):

did you check ActiveMQ Ajax page (http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html)?

it shouldn't be that hard to configure it right. And feel free to post any related questions to the ActiveMQ user mailing list.

Cheers
Dejan

Answer (score 2):

It very much depends on your language framework. Here's a nice comparison:

http://cometdaily.com/maturity.html

It doesn't contain the new one my company just released for .NET environments, [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync), but otherwise is fairly comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

Well , cometd is not very hard to configure .. you would get examples in the comed site....

it has two methods subscribe and publish , for doing a ajax push u have to subscribe to a channel and publish the content to the channel .. thats the basic use ... we used the same methodlogy.

There are to version of cometd implementations   dojo and jquery  .. we used dojo's . It doesn't matter which one u use .. once u see the examples u would understand ....

This subscribe and publish methodology is good for chat applications and also broadcasting over the network ...

for website design and backend functionalities ... we used j2ee framework and jetty webserver .....

If I understand ur question correctly ... u have to install Jetty 7 ( webtide version ) .. only this version supports Cometd ....  by install I mean unzip :-) .. its so easy ... in the web apps folder u get a cometd folder with examples .. understand this examples properly .. your web application's jsp pages would be using the javascripts to subscribe and publish .... now in publish function you would be calling  certain javascript function, which would in turn call a "div" ... thats how u publish or broadcast ur content ....

I assume u r familiar about javascript , jsp's and servlets ...

imashok2000(dot)gmail(dot)com

thanks ,
Ashok

Comment: Thanks Ashok, this question outdated little bit for me but what you tell is really interesting and worths to try, i'll try it in coming future for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider the Lift framework on top of the Jetty container. It has from my understanding very good support for comet style web development.

[www.liftweb.net](http://www.liftweb.net)